# How to avoid and controll the increment of files app.log.X in JAVA LOGGIN

Tags: java, logging, war, filehandler

I am fighting with some thing from yesterday.

I want to log a webapp (WAR) in java.

I create a log, append a FileHandler, and i send log messages. But, like all of us know, the file handler keep the lock over the new file until i call fush() and close(), so, when i redeploy the war (or if i run it in develop, and i continously deploy the app) it create one file per deploy (ugly).

So, I was trying to avoid this behavior, (I am not sure if it is done by a thing of performance this way, maybe open and close file everytime is expensive, i am not sure) but i want to atach the handler and flush/close each time the Logger log a message. (So i have only one file).

But i dont find any way to do this. I try to extends a java.util.Logger class and is so hard... (and -advised against- by some people).

Some one has any clue on how can i aproach this situation?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class LogUtil {

public static String name = "app%g.log";

public static Logger obtenerLogger(String eid, String path, Level levelToLog) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(eid);
    if (levelToLog != null) {
        logger.setLevel(levelToLog);
    }

    //I create the folder if not exist
    File dirFile = new File(path);
    if (!dirFile.exists()) {
        dirFile.mkdirs();
    }

    //I remove the handlers and close after each logg call (doing this i can use the same file lof after log)
    for (Handler handler : logger.getHandlers()) {
        logger.removeHandler(handler);
        handler.close();
        handler.flush();
    }

    //I Create the FileHandler 
    FileHandler f;
    try {
        f = new FileHandler(
                path + name, //pattern
                10485760, //limit
                3, // count
                true); //append
        //f.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        f.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
        f.setLevel(levelToLog);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }

    logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
    logger.addHandler(f);

    return logger;
}
```

PD1: But at redeploy of the war, i call the logger class, it create a new logger, but the last one keep unclose. And that is what is bothering me (i think)

Comment: post your logger setup/configuration please

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [How to create the log file for each record in a specific format using java util logging framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488028/how-to-create-the-log-file-for-each-record-in-a-specific-format-using-java-util/20499365#20499365)

I must extends a Handler and reimplement the publish method. (I was trying to implement the Logger class to close after each log call. DON'T Do That! jeje).

Thanks for your interes!

Answer (score 0):

> I create a log, append a FileHandler, and i send log messages. But, like all of us know, the file handler keep the lock over the new file until i call fush() and close(), so, when i redeploy the war (or if i run it in develop, and i continously deploy the app) it create one file per deploy (ugly).

If you are programmatically setting up your logger tree and handler you should implement a custom [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and register it with your web application.  Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716711/google-app-engine-configure-default-logger-to-send-email/29676725#29676725).

Also make sure you are [you are holding a strong reference to your loggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923754/selenium-many-logs-how-to-remove/40934452#40934452)