# Google Cloud Logging Handler Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, java.util.logging

My google app engine local development server returns a classdef not found exception when I point the logger to google clouds logging handler, how do I fix this?

```
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Can't load log handler "com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1165)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:556)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at coffee.weneed.chat.CoffeeChat.<clinit>(CoffeeChat.java:37)
    at coffee.weneed.chat.kik.KikServlet.doGet(KikServlet.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at ...
```

my logging.properties:

```
.level = INFO
io.grpc.netty.level=INFO
sun.net.level=INFO

coffee.weneed.chat.CoffeeChat.handlers=com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.log=coffee_chat
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.level=INFO

com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.flushLevel=SEVERE
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%3$s: %5$s%6$s
```

and my system properties:

```
    <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
```

I have included the cloud logging into the maven deps, the cloud maven plugin is installed. I just can't quite find out why it won't load the class.

Comment: I ended up using the [logback](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java) feature as I could not figure out how to get JUL to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You have to use code to install a custom handler in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841172/how-to-add-custom-log-handler-to-google-app-engine).  This is described as a [feature request for GAE](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35898548). It is also a known issue with the JDK as [JDK-6878454: LogManager class loading inconsistent with Java EE best practices](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6878454).

The issue is that the LogManager uses the system class loader to locate handlers but your code is located in a web app class loader which will be a child class loader.  The child class loader can locate classes in the parent but not the other way around.  This is the cause of your `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

You can follow [this example setting up a custom handler setup in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716711/google-app-engine-configure-default-logger-to-send-email).  This uses a `ServletContextListener` to gain access to the correct class loader.

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm! I ended up using [this code](https://pastebin.com/zTMkJf7b) to emulate the logging.properties I put above incase anybody wants to see how.