# Google App Engine Java 11 Unable to instantiate the com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

I'm are currently testing migration to Java 11 and I'm having issues with the logging component. In Java 8, everything was logging correctly, with the appropriate log level and aggregating logs into request. However, after moving to Java 11 that is no longer the case.

I went through the following guides:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/writing-application-logs
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#the_javautillogging_handler
I made the required changes to our code and now the server crashes upon initialization. I get the following error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract com.google.api.gax.rpc.TransportChannelProvider withExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)' of interface com.google.api.gax.rpc.TransportChannelProvider. at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:140) at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:123) at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:132) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:61) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:55) at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:561) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions.getLoggingRpcV2(LoggingOptions.java:129) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.(LoggingImpl.java:109) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:46) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:41) at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:541) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.getLogging(LoggingHandler.java:362) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.(LoggingHandler.java:195) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.(LoggingHandler.java:151) at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.(LoggingHandler.java:120) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584) at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.createLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:1000) at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:970) at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:966) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:966) at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1199) at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:525) at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:515) at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:654) at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:717) at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:701) at com.altairix.comm.adf.root.log.DefaultLogger.(DefaultLogger.java:26) at com.altairix.comm.adf.root.log.LoggerFactory.(LoggerFactory.java:7) at com.altairix.adf.Adf_Server.(Adf_Server.java:234) at com.altairix.adf.root.servlet.AdfServlet.(AdfServlet.java:98) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2372) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1166) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1207) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:588) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:472) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.ensureInstance(ServletHolder.java:767) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:752) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

The last call our code makes is: com.altairix.comm.adf.root.log.DefaultLogger.(DefaultLogger.java:26), which is:

```
logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DefaultLogger.class.getName());
```

I'm not sure if my logging.properties file is correct, but it was copied from one of the guides above

```
.level = INFO
io.grpc.netty.level=INFO
sun.net.level=INFO
com.altairix.adf.root.log.ServerLogger.handlers=com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler
com.altairix.comm.adf.root.log.DefaultLogger.handlers=com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.log=custom_log
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.level=FINEST
default : ERROR
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.flushLevel=ERROR
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.resourceType=container
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%3$s: %5$s%6$s
```

Comment: Looks like this is related to the logging handler though I'm still not sure. Can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778891/google-cloud-logging-handler-not-found if it is helpful.

Comment: I wasn't running into a class not found exception, but it was somewhat similar. I ended up having to use a custom handler com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler, but there is still an issue with the logging.properties file that I think it a bug on google's end

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding a handler to the logger:

```
import com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler;
...
logger.addHandler(new LoggingHandler());
```

and also removing the reference to the logging.properties file, but I don't believe this is the intended use and it seems there is a bug when trying to use the logging.properties file

Comment: There is a feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/35898548 regarding ‘Allow custom loggers for Java AppEngine’.You can add more details there in the FR.