# Use logging.properties with standard Appengine Java 11

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty, java.util.logging, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to do some Logging modification on My Standard AppEngine Java 11 app using a `logging.properties` file, My app is a Jetty web-server which I run by adding the following entry-point to my `app.yaml` file

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" com.jettymain.Main webapp.war'
```

Now Google documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#javautillogging_configuration) suggests that in order to use `logging.properties`. The path to the configuration file must be provided to your application as a system property: `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties`

I have tried setting that in the code, first thing in the com.jettymain.Main class which starts the Jetty embedded web-server by doing the following

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "WEB-INF/logging.properties")
```

But that didn't work, modifying the entry-point in `app.yaml` did make the web-server load those configurations but it was failing to load the Google cloud logging handler class `com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler`, which I need to write those logs to Google Stackdriver, I have the Google cloud logging dependency added to both my app and the web-server but that didn't help.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

modified entry-pint

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" com.jettymain.Main webapp.war -Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/logging.properties'
```

logging.properties file, it is the sample file which can be found [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging/blob/master/samples/snippets/src/main/resources/logging.properties) plus few extra things

```
# To use this configuration, add to system properties : -Djava.util.logging.config.file="/path/to/file"
.level = INFO

# it is recommended that io.grpc and sun.net logging level is kept at INFO level,
# as both these packages are used by Cloud internals and can result in verbose / initialization problems.
io.grpc.netty.level=INFO
sun.net.level=INFO

handlers=com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler
# default : java.log
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.log=custom_log

# default : INFO
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.level=FINE

# default : ERROR
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.flushLevel=EMERGENCY

# default : auto-detected, fallback "global"
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.resourceType=container

# custom formatter
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%3$s: %5$s%6$s

# Level for all logs coming from GWT client (can't filter by specific classes on client)
com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil.level = WARNING
com.beoui.geocell.level=WARNING
```

Comment: I assume you are using java.util.logging handler for setting up Cloud Logging for Java and not the Cloud logging library for Java directly?

Answer (score 1):

It might be an old question, but this answer still might help to someone having same issue.

I've managed to add custom `logging.properties` using Gradle for Java 11 Standard Environment:

1. First of all, you have to add dependency to the Cloud logging as it's no longer provided by the environment:

   ```
   dependencies {
     runtimeOnly("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:3.11.3")
     // your other dependencies
   }
   ```
2. Then you need to specify a folder containing your `logging.properties` file to be uploaded by Gradle `com.google.cloud.tools.appengine` plugin:

   ```
   configure<AppEngineAppYamlExtension> {
     stage {
       setArtifact("build/libs/server.jar")
       // can be some other folder of your choice where logging.properties is located
       setExtraFilesDirectories("src/main/resources")
     }
     deploy {
       version = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
       projectId = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Then specify an entrypoint in `app.yaml`. The trick here is that properties file can be found in `/workspace/` directory of the GAE container:

   ```
   runtime: java11
   entrypoint: 'java -jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/workspace/logging.properties server.jar'
   ```
4. Deploy application using

   ```
   ./gradlew appengineDeploy
   ```

My `logging.properties` file:

```
.level = INFO

# it is recommended that io.grpc and sun.net logging level is kept at INFO level,
# as both these packages are used by Cloud internals and can result in verbose / initialization problems.
io.grpc.netty.level=INFO
sun.net.level=INFO

handlers=com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%3$s: %5$s%6$s
```

Comment: Thank you, since then I have managed to supply the logging.properties file to my app, switched to the Legacy java 11 runtime and provided it to the app through appengine-web.xml file as a system property same as we used to do with gen 1

My problem now is that when I start the app I get a problem similar to what is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778891/google-cloud-logging-handler-not-found

Comment: @montss I believe it's related to the fact that google cloud logging dependency have to be provided with the application itself, at least from my tests

Comment: Yes the Logging Handler class should be available to the system class loader during the app creation, which I still don't have a sleek way to do yet

Comment: @montss The only why I was able to install a handler in was to use a [ServletContextListener 
 to install the handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716711/google-app-engine-configure-default-logger-to-send-email).

Answer (score -1):

Get the `System.setProperty` into any method. It can be the main method also. I think the problem is "`the logging.properties` must go in `WEB-INF/classes directory`" as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361928/15803365) and not `WEB-INF/` directory as mentioned in your code.

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties")
```

Comment: Not sure where to execute this command, in Appengine Standard environment app.yaml entrypoint seems the only place to do similar thing, and I tried that as I mentioned but it didn't work.

Comment: Execute the command I posted in the answer in your terminal if you are a Mac user or in Command Line if you are a Windows User. You can use Cloud Shell too. Specify your MainClass and provide the correct path.

Comment: I want to run  my app on a Deployed standard Appengine environment in the could, so I don't have access to any terminal, I don't have any problem with the app or the logs locally.

Comment: Okay I get it now. As mentioned in the Google docs "The path to the configuration file must be provided to your application as a system property: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties". You are translating this path/to/ logging.properties to be " WEB-INF/logging.properties". Why do you think it should be set as WEB-INF/logging.properties?

Comment: Because I have my logging.properties file in that directory.
The question is how to do the  "The path to the configuration file must be provided to your application as a system property".

Comment: Just get the System.setProperty into any method. It can be the main method also. I think the problem is "the logging.properties must go in WEB-INF/classes directory" as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361928/15803365) and not WEB-INF/ directory as mentioned in your code.

Comment: @montss Did you try setting System.setProperty in your main method like this System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties")? Please let me know if this resolved your issue.